# AWS S3- CloudFront upload through mobile app - Corrupted files

Tags: cordova, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I've recently built a service to upload files directly to S3 with Cloudfront - SignedUrl using FileTransfer - Cordova.
Everything looks fine, I get the following response:

```
{"BytesSent": -numOfBytes-, "responseCode": 200, "objectId":""}
```

but I can't access this file - can't read, change, download got failed. Probably the files are corrupted, Just weird.
the upload code -

```
let uri = data['signed_request'];

const ft: TransferObject = this.transfer.create();

let options : FileUploadOptions = {
  fileKey: "file",
  fileName: fileName,
  mimeType: self.settings[kind].type,
  chunkedMode: false,
  httpMethod: 'PUT',
  headers: {
     'Content-Type': self.settings[kind].type,
     'X-Amz-Acl': 'public-read'
  }
}

ft.onProgress = function(progressEvent) {
  if (progressEvent.length) {

  } else {

  }
};
ft.upload(file, uri, options, true).then((data) => {
   resolve(data['readURL']);
}).catch((err) => {
   resolve("Could not upload file. => " + err);
});
```

What do you think could be wrong? - I can't see any reasonable reason and stuck on this for too long..
Thanks

Comment: *"Probably the files are corrupted"* sounds like you are guessing.  What do you see in the bucket, using the S3 console?  Are the files there?  What size are they?  What do you see in the logs for CloudFront and S3?

Comment: Doesn't matter, I've already succeeded accomplish that. I needed to convert fileURI to canvas then base64 then to blob to make it work properly with cloudfront/s3 in any device. Thanks anyway!